# Метка времени в минутах

Tags: php

Уважаемые Коллеги.
У меня есть число 300 -это количество секунд ,соответственно ровно 5 минутам.
Как мне конвертировать это число в Unix формат

Comment: Может быть это вам поможет http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php

Comment: Что ещё за Unix формат? можно поподробнее?

Answer (score 1):

В общем то [Юникс время](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIX-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F) измеряется в секундах и это определенный временной отрезок.

Как мне конвертировать это число в Unix формат - немного некорректно задан вопрос - тут либо текущее время +5 мин, либо текущее время минус 5 мин, потому как Юникс время это всегда конкретный промежуток времени и скаждой новой секундой он увеличивается

```
$a=time()+300;$a=time()-500;//и никак иначе
//результат будет в Unix формате
```

исправлено на:

```
$a=time()+300;$a=time()-300;
```

Если речь идет о хранении значений разницы во времени - то я обычно храню в разных столбцах - в одном время начала, в другом время окончания, а формат на ваше усмотрение

Comment: согласен 500 это ошибка необходимо 300. Я в курсе что время это не формат, но если бы я был на месте новичка я бы так и задал вопрос. Каков по вашему уровень подготовки задающего вопросы? и Каков должен быть ответ по вашему? Возможно здесь вообще речь идет о том как хранить значение временного отрезка в базе и вопрос некорректный, в таком случае почему не минусовался вопрос вот это мне больше чем непонятно